# Get all the Sunday,Tuesday,Wednesday for whole year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have the below requirement:

1. Need to get all the Sunday,Tuesday,Wednesday date for year 2019.
2. once we get date for these days so column should be "FromDate" & "ToDate"
3. If Sunday,Wednesday for date should be 5:00:00 Pm(FromColumn) to 6:00:00 PM (ToColumn) similarly for Tuesday datetime should for FromColumn 8:00:00 AM to 9:00:00 AM in (Tocolumn)
4. After that we need to enter this column "FromDate" & "Todate" store in physical table those are exists in DB

I am using above logic but not able to update "ToDate"column and also not able to insert data in physical table.

Comment: Do not post *images* of text. Code should be copied and pasted directly into your question, not screen-shotted.

Comment: Hi @Khushi. Please repair this question as per the guidance you have received in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all dates using a numbers table or recursive CTE.  The rest is just date arithmetic and filtering:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(datetime, '2019-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2019-12-31'
     )
select (case when datename(weekday, dte) in ('Sunday', 'Wednesday')
             then dateadd(hour, 17, dte)
             else dateadd(hour, 8, dte)
        end) as FromDate,
       (case when datename(weekday, dte) in ('Sunday', 'Wednesday')
             then dateadd(hour, 18, dte)
             else dateadd(hour, 9, dte)
        end) as ToDate       
from dates
where datename(weekday, dte) in ('Sunday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday')
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c264bf3010a30641f087e61e499644c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Appreciate your response but this data need to insert in existing table so can we insert direct or need to add to store in temporarty table.Please suggest to insert this coloumn value in existing tbale with other coloumn vlaues

Comment: @hkushi . . . You can use a recursive CTE with either an `insert` or `update`.